# Opening images in lightbox asp.net/linq2sql with querystring parameter

Tags: asp.net, query-string, lightbox

Don't know if this is possible, but i have a site with categories, when you click a category i want it to redirect to the same page, but with a querystring parameter of the category id.

The page will then load a lightbox to open the images with the correct category id.

That is my basic thought. if any1 has a better ide, i'll gladly listen.
Dont worry about the linq2sql parts, that i am sure how to do... its more the lightbox/querystring problem i want help to solve.

Answer (score 0):

Just assign the Url to the image you want to show via lightbox and it should work

Comment: Not sure how you mean, if i click the category with lets say id 3. The url will be: http://www.mydomain.com/default.aspx?id=3